# Difference between TELNET Command in cmd.exe and Socket programming in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, command-line, cmd, telnet

I have a machine to which i am getting connected using TELNET command in cmd.exe  by passing ip address and port number.After the successful connection i am passing some commands to get the task done.But opening command prompt each time and doing the task like mentioned is not the thing that client wants.They want the process to be automated.With Some experience in Socket programs in c#,i tried to connect through socket program by using ip address and port number and pass the commands to get the task done but socket programming is not doing the task .

So my question is, Is it possible to do the same task done by telnet command in cmd.exe using Socket programming in c# and if yes how?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code in c# to get connected to the machine but it is not able to do the desired task.It is not able to perform the task that is being done by TELNET command in cmd.exe..

```
            int intport;
            int.TryParse(port1, out intport);

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            textfileSaveLocation = "some location";

            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Before Connection !");
                }

                client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), intport));

                Thread.Sleep(5000);


                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Connected To Machine !");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the error here.
                client.Close();

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Connection Error !");
                }

                continue;
            }

            try
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {

                    byte[] username = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + "\r\n");
                    stream.Write(username, 0, username.Length);

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("UserName Enetered !");
                    }

                    byte[] password = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass + "\r\n");
                    stream.Write(password, 0, password.Length);

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Password Passed !");
                    }

                    byte[] terminal = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(port2 + "\r\n");
                    stream.Write(terminal, 0, terminal.Length);

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Terminal Value Entered !");
                    }


                client.Close();
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think the telnet protocol is more than just text, it uses control characters and the like as well.

Comment: @Ashigore While executing above program i am not getting any error but the task that needs to be done is not happening whereas by using TELNET in cmd.exe i am able to accomplish the task..Why is this happening

Comment: I think because the commands you are sending are not correctly encoded.

Comment: @Ashigore Then in which formate i should send?

Comment: You can start by reading the Telnet Protocol specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible.

Google search keywords: C# Telnet CLient

First result: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library

Comment: Sir please see my updated post with the socket codes that i am trying to execute ,,but it is not accomplishing the task.

Answer (score 1):

A simple client can be written using [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
var client = new TcpClient("localhost", 25);
const string crlf = "\r\n";
var networkStream = client.GetStream();
var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

// Receive data from server
var serverResponse = streamReader.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Server: " + serverResponse);

// Send data to server
const string data = "Command to server " + crlf;
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

networkStream.Close();
client.Close();
```

Comment: Exactly same is there in my program too.See it

Comment: Not exactly. This one reads from the server too. Try to read responses from the server. That might be your issues.

Comment: Is it needed to read the server response every time.What impact it would put if not read and why?

Comment: Is there any difference in establishing connection from cmd.exe using TELNET command and Sockets in c#

Comment: Its about the protocol. Essentially it's basically TCP communication and no difference in that sense. The difference is the protocol: the oreder of messages being sent and received etc

Comment: But why i am not getting any type of error or exception

Answer (score 0):

Let us revive the dead (old) question.

I'm on the contrary, is looking for a way to do socket programming with [SuperSocket](http://docs.supersocket.net/v1-6/en-US/A-Telnet-Example). I tried, and it works with telnet from cmd.